# Relating Mongodb Subdocuments

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm building a REST api in node and i'm stuck on trying to include subdocuments into my GET requests. For example, I have two schema's right now, People and Locations. A location can have many people, and a person can have one location. So when you return /people I would like my location entry to contain the location information.

I believe my problem could be one of two things. I'm fairly new to node, so i'm not 100% sure if my schema's can see each other, when I try the common methods around the web, my location field get's populated with null. How I understand it, I store the location id in my people schema and then using subdocuments it will find the location with that id and fill in the info.

I also am not 100% sure how to use the populate function, and how exactly I should go about writing the response to my GET call. My code below, I'd love to hear what you have to say!

app.js

```
// Node Setup
var application_root = __dirname,
express = require('express'),
path = require('path'),
mongoose = require('mongoose'),
http = require('http');
var app = express();

// MongoDB Connection
var dbLocalhost = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost/lantern/');

// Configure Node
app.configure(function(){
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(app.router);
    app.use(express.static(path.join(application_root, "public")));
    app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true }));
app.port = 3000;
});

// Routes
var Locations = require('./routes/locations')(app, { 'mongoose': mongoose, 'db': dbLocalhost });
var People = require('./routes/people')(app, { 'mongoose': mongoose, 'db': dbLocalhost });

// Start the server
app.listen(app.port);
```

routes/people.js - has all the endpoints, but we're just concerned with GET for now

```
module.exports = function (app, options) {

    var mongoose = options.mongoose;
    var Schema = options.mongoose.Schema;
    var db = options.db;
    var PeopleModel = require('../schemas/peopleSchema')(db);

    app.get('/people', function (req, res) {
        return PeopleModel.find(function (err, obj) {
          if (!err) {
            return res.send(obj);
          } else {
            return res.send(err);
          }
        });   
    });
};
```

schemas/peopleSchema.js (the "location" field is what i want to populate)

```
module.exports = function(db) { 
return db.model('People', PeopleSchema());
}

function PeopleSchema () {
var Schema = require('mongoose').Schema;

    return new Schema({
    first_name: String,
    last_name: String,
    address: {
        unit: Number,
        address: String,
        zipcode: String,
        city: String,
        region: String,
        country: String
    },
    image: String, 
    job_title: String,
    created_at: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    active_until: { type: Date, default: null },
    hourly_wage: Number,
    location: [{type: Schema.ObjectId , ref: 'Locations'}], // Inheirit store info
    employee_number: Number
    }, { collection: 'people' });


}
```

schemas/locationsSchema.js - and the locations schema just incase

```
module.exports = function(db) {
return db.model('Locations', LocationsSchema());    
}

function LocationsSchema () {
    var Schema = require('mongoose').Schema;

    return new Schema({
    title: String,
    address: {
        unit: Number,
        address: String,
        zipcode: String,
        city: String,
        region: String,
        country: String
    },
    current_manager: String, // Inherit person details
    alternate_contact: String, // Inherit person details
    hours: {
        sunday: String,
        monday: String,
        tuesday: String,
        wednesday: String,
        thursday: String,
        friday: String,
        saturday: String,
        holidays: String
    },
    employees: "", // mixin employees that work at this location
    created_at: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    active_until: { type: Date, default: null }
    }, { collection: 'locations' });
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [populate mongoose subdocuments with REST api](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18807958/populate-mongoose-subdocuments-with-rest-api)

Comment: If you're worried about relationships between these two things, are you sure you're using the correct database technology? Mongo is designed to have collections that do **not** relate. You might be better modelling this in something like Postgres or MySQL.